# Emberjs: Append tr and td to table

Tags: ember.js

Am enjoying my first foray into the world of ember, but have stumbled a bit when doing something relatively simple.

I'm wanting to append a handlebars template of  elements using a class tagName: "tr" However dont sometimes the elements get inserted but dont show, and other times its simply a Nx list of  and no  terminator. If I were to manually add  it will output the first row perfectly but then halt..

```
{{#each App.variantController.content}}
            <td class="cen"><input class="variant" id="variant-{{unbound pk}}" type="checkbox"></input></td>
            <td class="value">{{sku}}</td>
            <td class="value">{{cost}}</td>
            {{#each basic_product_options}}
            <td class="value">{{content}}</td>
            {{/each}}
            <td class="value cen">
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#editVariationModal" class="btn btn-mini btn-warning">{% trans 'Edit' %}</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini disabled pull-right"><i class="icon-resize-vertical"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}​
```

JavaScript:

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.Variant = Em.Object.extend({
    pk: null,
    cost: null,
    sku: null
});

App.variantController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function() {
        variants = eval($('script#data-variant_list').html());
        for (var i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
            this.pushObject(App.Variant.create(variants[i]));
        }
    }
});

App.VariantView = Em.View.create({
    tagName: 'tr',
    classNames: ['variant'],
    templateName: 'hb-variant-list'
});

App.VariantView.appendTo('#variants-list');​
```

the jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GJASM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got something almost working @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/qhPLt/

Comment: That is a great bit of advice.. thanks a tonne.. Have got it "working" however I cant seem to get it to append the view into the appropriate div: App.VariantsView.create({
    variantsBinding: 'App.variantsController'
}).appendTo('my-div');

Comment: Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/qhPLt/27/

:) You are missing the '#' for id reference...

Comment: LOL... always the basics.. hey thanks allot :) really helped me out there.. I will study this foo now :)